# Draw a rectangle in libgdx and increase its length

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to libgdx.

This is what I know:

We can create a rectangular box with red color using this:

```
  shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
  shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
  shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
  shapeRenderer.end();
```

What I want to know:

I want this rectangle to persist between different frames.what I want is to create a rectangle object, and increase its length after every 3 seconds or so.

How to do this esactly? as from what i gather, if i use this code in betwen batch.begin() and batch.end() of render, it will create a new box in every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an integer instance in your main class such as shape_length, and have it increase every every 3 second through storing a another variable that would be set to 0 after its accumulated delta time is more than or equal to 3 seconds.

```
//member functions
private int shape_length = 300;
private float total_time = 0f;

//inside render loop
public void render(float deltaTime){
total_time += deltaTime;
if(total_time >= 3.0f){
    //add 1 to length every 3 seconds
    shape_length += 1;
    total_time = 0.f;
}
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, shape_length, 20);
shapeRenderer.end();
//fun times here
}
```

Update: The author wanted a way to have the rectangle as a usable class and not something constantly drawn every frame, so here's an alternative solution:

What could work is that you create a class such as RectShape that could store relative information such as height, width, a Vector2 position, etc, and then have a method on your main class that would specifically render your RectShape as follows:

```
class RectShape {
private float width;
    private float height;
    private Vector2 pos;
    private Color color;
    public RectShape(float w, float h, Vector2 p){
        width = w;
        height = h;
        pos = p;
    }

    public void increaseLength(){
        width += 2.f;
    }
    //getters: getColor(), getPosition(), getWidth, getHeight()

 }
```

Create a drawRectangle method that takes both the RectShape object and ShapeRenderer

```
public void drawRectangle(RectShape mainRect, ShapeRenderer renderer){
    renderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
    renderer.setColor(mainRect.getColor());
    renderer.filledRect(mainRect.getPosition().x,mainRect.getPosition().y,mainRect.getWidth(),mainRect.getHeight());
```

Then, on your main file

```
//instantiate object
RectShape s = new RectShape(300.f,200.f,new Vector2(3,2));

//render loop
total_time += deltaTime;
if(total_time >= 3.0f){
    //add 1 to length every 3 seconds
    s.increaseLength();
    total_time = 0.f;
}
shapeRenderer.begin();
drawRectangle(s,shapeRenderer);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done so far, but i dont want to redraw the same rectangle every frame - i want it to 'persist' between frames. Any idea to to this?

Comment: In OpenGL every frame the `Screenbuffer` is cleared `glClear(..)` - It is not possible to have part of the screen beeing persistent nor is there a use to this a.k.a you won't lose any performance

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: The rectangle data is now coming from a persistent object, but it is still redrawn every frame :)

Comment: I'm not sure there's any other way for Arnab to get out of rendering the rectangle every time, I just assumed by "persistent" he wanted a persistent object.

Answer (score 0):

The box is redrawn every frame yes.

To increase the length (a.k.a width) of the rectangle over time you could work with a timer:

In your game class have a variable for length

```
int rectWidth = 300;
int counter = 0; // And a counter
```

In your `update(float delta)` method you can now modify the width of the rectangle.
If your games runs at 60 Frames per second ** , the render method is called 60times/second. So to update the width of the rectangle every 3 seconds do:

```
public void update(float delta) {

    if(counter > 60 * 3) {
        rectWidth++;
        counter = 0;
    }

}

public void render() {

    [...]
    shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, rectWidth, 20);
    [...]
    counter++;
}
```

There are better methods to do time dependent tasks but this should give you a starting point.

** You can define the framerate by setting `ForegroundFPS`

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.foregroundFPS = 60;
```

Comment: How about limiting frame rate for Android? What is the pro/con doing it this way verses using the `getDeltaTime` method?

Comment: DeltaTime is more acurate. You should always use delta: I.e for moving the character `playerX = playerX + (speed * delta)` - On Android i would limit the framerate to save battery life etc. The right FPS depends on your gametype

Comment: Sine DeltaTime returns an int seconds I am confused as to what it does? It returns 0 until it returns 1? Also you should include in your answer how to limit the frames in android for the sake of completeness.

Comment: delta is a float. As he is using the libGDX library delta is calculated for him an the last two lines in my answer show how to limit the framerate.

Comment: I guess it is a glitch in the documentation the Gdx.graphics.getDelta says it returns an int.

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the rectangles length you need to replace the 300 and 20 with variables.

```
 shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
```

should be

```
 shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, rWidth, rHeight);
```

Then declare those variables in your class

```
int rWidth,rHeight;
```

and put this in your default constructor

```
rWidth=300;
rHeight=20;
```

Then in your render class you will have a seperate method in the beginning of it that will increase the rWidth and rHeight. To make it grow very quickly you can just put this in the top of your render method.

```
rWidth++;
rHeight++;
```

try this for now so you get the idea then you can use `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` to adjust it based on time rather than rendering frames.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to redraw even a simple object as a rectangle on the camera on every frame, and there is no way to persist a shapeRenderer object between frames?

Comment: @Arnab I am pretty sure you have to redraw it because once it finishes drawing it loses scope. You can't make it persist because nothing exists. OpenGL is drawing it to the screen and it is only an artifact on the screen there is no collision detection or anything like that associated with it.